# Scala - implicit conversion with unapply

Tags: scala, implicit-conversion, unapply

I'd like an extractor to implicitly convert its parameters, but it doesn't seem to work.  Consider this very simple case:

```
case class MyString(s: String) {}

implicit def string2mystring(x: String): MyString = new MyString(x)
implicit def mystring2string(x: MyString) = x.s

object Apply {
    def unapply(s: MyString): Option[String] = Some(s)
}
```

But I'm not able to use it as I would expect:

```
val Apply(z) = "a"  // error: scrutinee is incompatible with pattern type
```

Can anyone explain why it fails to convert the parameter from `String` to `MyString`?  I would expect it to call `string2mystring("a")` on the fly.  Clearly I could work around the issue by saying `val Apply(y) = MyString("a")`, but it doesn't seem like I should have to do that.

Note: This question is similar to [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1820777/is-it-possible-to-use-implicit-conversions-for-parameters-to-extractors-unapply), but 1) that one doesn't really have a good answer for why this is happening, 2) the example is more complex than it needs to be.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Implicit conversions are not applied when pattern matching. That's not a bug or a problem with your code, it's simply a design decision of the creators of Scala.

To fix it, you should write another extractor that accepts a `String` — which in turn can call your implicit conversion.

Alternatively, you can try with a view bound, which seems to work as well, and will also work if you later define other implicit conversions to `MyString`:

```
object Apply {
  def unapply[S <% MyString](s: S): Option[String] = Some(s.s)
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  That's a bit disappointing.  Do you know what the motivation is for that decision?

Comment: Yep, adding `def unapply(p: String): Option[String] = Some(p)` to `Apply` does the trick.  So I'll go with that.  Thanks.

Comment: @dhg I edited the answer — a view bound seems to work as well.

Comment: Awesome!  The view bound is a great solution.  Not only does it not require writing additional methods for every possible type, but it solves another problem I had: If `unapply` takes a tuple, you can't use the overloading trick due to type erasure.  But this solves it cleanly and results in compile-time errors for wrong arg types: 

`def unapply[S <% MyString](p: (S, Int)): Option[String] = Some(p._1.s + p._2)`.